# Guess location from city

Tags: autocomplete

I am developing a site where users can find/post - well, let's say - "things". These "things" have name, description, etc.. and the most important information about them is their location. The location consists of the city (country, sometimes state) and the street.

There is no separate input for country and state, because I want it to be filled automatically, I would like to give a list for the city, where the country and the state is given (for example the user types new, then he gets New York, NY, and other guesses.

My question is, that how could I do this most efficiently? (The site can be used from all over the world)

Thanks

Comment: I got excited about answering a potential GeoLocation question, but then got to the end and still didn't spot a genuine question. Can you try and rephrase so it actually asks something, rather than "most efficient". You haven't made any suggestions to even suggest a most efficient way.

Comment: When I said efficiently I meant that I would like to do it fast, to give the user the best experience. Since I haven't done anything similar before, I do not really have an idea, and I do not know where to begin.

Comment: I think he wants to know how to implement it the best way. E.g. how to implement and use a corresponding web service or how to supply a database, ...

Comment: My main question is not exactly about the programming side, but about the services I should use.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a service such as [Geobytes API](http://www.geobytes.com/free-ajax-cities-jsonp-api.htm). It will provide you a way to autocomplete the city name, and then get its country, region, latitude/longitude, currency, etc.

You can perform up to 50,000 requests a day, which is enough for many cases.

Does it answer your question ?